# How do I get Excel to refresh a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry I'm new to macros.

Essentially what I need done is if a cells value is "ERROR" then refresh the cell to check for new data. I have the msgbox there to make sure I have everything up to that working. I'm not attached to this code if theres a better method.

```
Sub Cell_Looping1()

'c = cell

For Each c In Selection

'Do this
If c.Value = "ERROR" Then
MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " needs to be refreshed"



End If

Next c
    End Sub
```

To add some context. “ERROR” happens when I pull too much data from the API. I generally resolve this by selecting the cell in error pressing F2 then Enter. This macro will make life so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replicate the action of pressing `F2` to edit/refresh/recalculate the cell without changing it.

```
Sub YourMacro()

Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If c.Value = "ERROR" Then c.Formula = c.Formula

    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: YOU'RE A SUPER HERO! works flawlessly. I've been trying to get help from reddit for days. Lesson learned.